# Relative fs.readFileSync paths with Node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to upload the photo from postman to the folder, but I got "no such file or directory". I guess it might be because I wrote :

```
fs.readFileSync("./uploads")
```

I have searched about ways to change the path, so I tried:

```
fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './uploads'))
```

Or:

```
fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'uploads'))
```

Still doesn't work, does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `path.join` instead:

```js
fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Things to consider:

- `__dirname` returns the base path for the current script. For example, if your JavaScript is located at `/my-project/src/foo.js`, then `__dirname == '/my-project/src'`.
- `./uploads` does not seem to be a photo file (where is the conventional extension, like `.png`?). Are you trying to enumerate files in a directory? If yes, then you should use `fs.readdirSync(...)`.

If possible, show your project structure so that we can see where `uploads` is located, and also show where is the entry point JavaScript.